# Combine PyCharm and CLion IDEs

Tags: python, c, intellij-idea, pycharm, clion

I am a student and have access to all JetBrains professional products.
In my project I use C, Python and Cython simultaneously and desperate for an IDE which will combine both Pycharm pro and Clion functionalities. Cython support is built in in Pycharm pro or its corresponding plugin. I tried many combinations of products but (on Ubuntu 14.04):

- on clion-2016.2.3 Python community eddition is built in but no Cython plugin is offered.
- on pycharm-2016.2.3 no C plugin is offered.
- on idea-IU-162.2228.15 I could install Python plugin but no C plugin is offered.

Obviously my question is: Which combination of IDE-plugin should I use to be able to use Python C and Cython? Maybe previous versions of these products? Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: how much of each type of code do yo write? Is it just python wrappers?

Comment: Yes its mostly extensions but I use Cython language which is supported only in Pycham pro or a corresponding plugin.

Answer (score 10):

CLion (v2016.1 and above) goes with [Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/#v2016-1-python) support from PyCharm Community edition, bundled by default.

And if you are interested in Cython in CLion, upvote this [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5652).

In the end, I don't think any other option is possible, since CLion is not currently available as a plugin to any other tool, only as a stand-alone IDE.